# excel vba conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to generate certain vells in Excel with predefined conditional formatting. If number 1 is entered the green icon from 3 symbols uncircled should be shown. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub AddIconCondFormat(cell1 As range, cell2 As range)

    range(cell1, cell2).Select
    With Selection
        .FormatConditions.Delete
       '.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:XlEqual, Formula1:
    End With

End Sub
```

I don't know all the necessary parameters for .FormatConditions. Does someone know if they are listed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using macro recording I got this code which works:

```
Sub AddIconCondFormat(cell1 As range, cell2 As range)

range(cell1, cell2).Select
With Selection
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
    .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols2)
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 33
        .Operator = 7
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValuePercent
        .Value = 67
        .Operator = 7
    End With
End With

End Sub
```